# Episerver Thumbnails for jpegs are getting a 404

Tags: jpeg, thumbnails, episerver

In Episerver 11, the thumbnails for jpegs are broken. In the media library, they display as broken images:

[image]

And I see this in the browser tools:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

On the actual url

```
https://mysite.mydomain.com/episerver/CMS/Content/siteassets/heros/myimage.jpg,,26/Thumbnail?epieditmode=False?1527614597161
```

On an actual web page and in the Image editor, they display fine. Not entirely sure how the thumbnail system works.

Comment: Are you using any third-party lib for image resizing etc?

Comment: No. No imageresizer or anything.

Comment: If you browse directly to the image URL, do you get a 404 or some other error? Logs say anything?

Comment: I can browse directly to the image without a problem. Its only the thumbnail.

Comment: I should have clarified that I meant the image _thumbnail_ URL. :)

Comment: Yes. Thats what I meant. I can browse to the thumbnail url

Comment: Ooops. Wrong. No, yount browse directly to the thumbail url. You get a 404.

Comment: Did you solve it? I am facing the same issue and can't find the soultion. We are using ImageResizer plugin though.

Comment: Sorry, this was a while ago. Im pretty sure we had custom code generating thumbnails and it was breaking them in this case. I proved this by removing my custom code, regenerating thumbnails, and the problem went away. Not really a solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your thumbnails are saved as png's.

I had the same problem, due to a third-party library for image resizing.
It turns out Episerver (CMS version 9.12), always wants to save the thumbnail for an image in a png format.

Comment: Hm. They are being saved as jpegs. Ill have to figure out why.

Comment: This is definitely the problem. Im not sure why they are getting saved a jpgs.

Answer (score 0):

Run the scheduled job "Clear Thumbnail Properties" in admin

From the [documentation](http://webhelp.episerver.com/latest/cms-admin/scheduled-jobs.htm)

> You can clear generated thumbnail images in the Products list and
>   Media list views and add them again with the Clear Thumbnail
>   Properties job. Run this job manually if you experience problems with
>   refreshing thumbnails, such as on the website and BLOB-supported
>   content.

Comment: This unfortunately did not fix the problem.

Comment: @EthanSchofer, In that case, I'm guessing privilege issues. Have you verified that the account running the IIS App pool have sufficient rights?

Comment: They have access to all the other thumbnails. Do you mean to the blobs folders? Its IIS express, so IIS has my privileges, and I have fill control over the blobs folder.